# Typescript function complain parameter type not assignable when added multiple types

Tags: typescript

I have a very simple function:

```
function foo<T>(input: T, def: T) : T {
    return !!input ? input : def;
}
```

so calling

```
foo(6, 7);
foo("h", "i")
```

are ok.

Now if I change to

```
function foo<T>(input: T | null | undefined, def: T) : T {
    return !!input ? input : def;
}
```

I got errors like "*Argument of type '6' is not assignable to parameter of type '7 | null | undefined'.*" and "*Argument of type '"h"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"i" | null | undefined'.*"

But if I call it like

```
const h: string = "h";
const i: string = "i";
foo(h, i);
```

Then it is ok.

Why is that?

Comment: why do you add null and undefined in the or condition ? I think it is taken as a single string variable type.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an issue for me? [See example of your problematic code on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfAChmABxCgC5ENEAfRMEAGzqsXABMBTYfNlgGkXeBkMASkRDEAbwBQiWYgBObKCHlIAhGvxEoiAPyItxMfw4BuKQF8pUlHBwA2PgHZh52zgBEACw98PMD1cpIA).

Comment: @Terry You are so quick! Yes, it seems only on earlier version?

Comment: Which version of TS are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes, it seems only on earlier version?

Yes, version 3.5.1 and below to be exact [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.5.1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfAChmABxCgC5ENEAfRMEAGzqsXABMBTYfNlgGkXeBkMASkRDEAbwBQiWYgBObKCHlIAhGvxEoiAPyItxMfw4BuKQF8pUlHBwA2PgHZh52zgBEACw98PMD1cpIA)

In this example:

```
function foo<T>(input: T | null | undefined, def: T) : T {
    return !!input ? input : def;
}

foo(6, 7);
foo("h", "i");
```

The generic argument is always the literal of the second parameter, which is why this throws an error.

In later versions, `null | undefined` does not affect the generic parameters anymore.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please also add in why first declaring the parameters works (my last example)?

Comment: @user1589188 This is pure speculation since I havent found a github issue to it, but it seems that typescript just had problems inferring the right type argument in that version. Explicitly declaring the type means typescript does not have to infer the type itself.

Comment: _I guess_ Typescript is smart enough to figure out that the `!!input` triggers on `null` and `undefined` and therefore `input` cannot be one of them. Hence `input` must be `T`. How they (the TS gang) solved that is beyond my understanding.